# Performing dplyr mutate on subset of columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame such as this (the real data set has many more rows and columns)

```
set.seed(15)
dd <- data.frame(id=letters[1:4], matrix(runif(5*4), nrow=4))

#   id        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5
# 1  a 0.6021140 0.3670719 0.6872308 0.5090904 0.4474437
# 2  b 0.1950439 0.9888592 0.8314290 0.7066286 0.9646670
# 3  c 0.9664587 0.8151934 0.1046694 0.8623137 0.1411871
# 4  d 0.6509055 0.2539684 0.6461509 0.8417851 0.7767125
```

I would like to be able to write a dplyr statement where I can select a subset of columns and mutate them. (I'm trying to do something similar to using .SDcols in data.table).

For a simplified example, here's the function I would like to be able to write to add columns for the sums and means of the even "X" columns while preserving all other columns. The desired output using base R is

```
(cols<-paste0("X", c(2,4)))
# [1] "X2" "X4"
cbind(dd,evensum=rowSums(dd[,cols]),evenmean=rowMeans(dd[,cols]))

#   id        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5   evensum  evenmean
# 1  a 0.6021140 0.3670719 0.6872308 0.5090904 0.4474437 0.8761623 0.4380811
# 2  b 0.1950439 0.9888592 0.8314290 0.7066286 0.9646670 1.6954878 0.8477439
# 3  c 0.9664587 0.8151934 0.1046694 0.8623137 0.1411871 1.6775071 0.8387535
# 4  d 0.6509055 0.2539684 0.6461509 0.8417851 0.7767125 1.0957535 0.5478768
```

but I wanted to use a dplyr-like chain to do the same thing. In the general case, I'd like to be able to use any of `select()`'s helper functions such as `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `matches`, etc and any function. Here's what I tried

```
library(dplyr)
partial_mutate1 <- function(x, colspec, ...) {
    select_(x, .dots=list(lazyeval::lazy(colspec))) %>% 
    transmute_(.dots=lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)) %>% 
    cbind(x,.)
}

dd %>% partial_mutate1(num_range("X", c(2,4)), 
    evensum=rowSums(.), evenmean=rowMeans(.))
```

However, This throws an error that says

```
Error in rowSums(.) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Which appears to be because `.` seems to be referring to the entire date.frame rather than the selected subset. (same error as `rowSums(dd)`). However, note that this produces the desired output

```
partial_mutate2 <- function(x, colspec) {
    select_(x, .dots=list(lazyeval::lazy(colspec))) %>% 
    transmute(evensum=rowSums(.), evenmean=rowMeans(.)) %>% 
    cbind(x,.)
}
dd %>% partial_mutate2(seq(2,ncol(dd),2))
```

I'm guessing this is some sort of environment problem? Any suggestions on how to pass the arguments to `partial_mutate1` so that the `.` will correctly take values from the "select()-ed" dataset?

Comment: An ugly way would be: `dd %>% select(X2, X4) %>% mutate(evensum = rowSums(.), evenmean = rowMeans(.)) %>% select(-X2, -X4) %>% cbind(., dd)`

Comment: I suspect the problem is that attempting the SE is messing with `%>%`.  In other words, with `rowMeans(.)` burried inside `.dots`, `%>%` has no way of knowing it should be substituting the data there as well.  This is just a guess.

Comment: I think you're right @BrodieG. After a bit more digging this is more of a magrittr issue than a dplyr issue. For example: `mutate(dd[,-1], sums=rowSums(.))` doesn't work ("object '.' not found"). So the `.` symbol isn't special to `dplyr`. Trying to use it to apply a function across columns seems to be the wrong idea. I guess I should be reshaping the data to a "tidy" format first.

Comment: Although SO shows the link on the right side, I thought it's better visible here: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33314971/mutate-and-rowsums-exclude-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1) helps how to use `starts_with` and other select helper functions - the syntax which was suggested by @Brandon Bertelsen now seems to work, i.e. `mutate(new_col = rowSums(select(., starts_with(string))))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Am I missing something or would this work as expected:

```
cols <- paste0("X", c(2,4))
dd %>% mutate(evensum = rowSums(.[cols]), evenmean = rowMeans(.[cols]))
#  id        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5   evensum  evenmean
#1  a 0.6021140 0.3670719 0.6872308 0.5090904 0.4474437 0.8761623 0.4380811
#2  b 0.1950439 0.9888592 0.8314290 0.7066286 0.9646670 1.6954878 0.8477439
#3  c 0.9664587 0.8151934 0.1046694 0.8623137 0.1411871 1.6775071 0.8387535
#4  d 0.6509055 0.2539684 0.6461509 0.8417851 0.7767125 1.0957535 0.5478768
```

Or are you specifically looking for a custom function to do this?

---

Not exactly what you are looking for but if you want to do it inside a pipe you could use `select` explicitly inside `mutate` like this:

```
dd %>% mutate(xy = select(., num_range("X", c(2,4))) %>% rowSums)
#  id        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5        xy
#1  a 0.6021140 0.3670719 0.6872308 0.5090904 0.4474437 0.8761623
#2  b 0.1950439 0.9888592 0.8314290 0.7066286 0.9646670 1.6954878
#3  c 0.9664587 0.8151934 0.1046694 0.8623137 0.1411871 1.6775071
#4  d 0.6509055 0.2539684 0.6461509 0.8417851 0.7767125 1.0957535
```

However, it is a bit more complicated if you want to apply several functions. You could use a helper function along the lines of (..not thoroughly tested.. ):

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
  n <- nrow(x)
  x <- lapply(list(...), function(y) if (length(y) == 1L) rep(y, n) else y)
  matrix(unlist(x), nrow = n, byrow = FALSE)
}
```

And then apply it like this:

```
dd %>% mutate(xy = select(., num_range("X", c(2,4))) %>% f(., rowSums(.), max(.)))
#  id        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5      xy.1      xy.2
#1  a 0.6021140 0.3670719 0.6872308 0.5090904 0.4474437 0.8761623 0.9888592
#2  b 0.1950439 0.9888592 0.8314290 0.7066286 0.9646670 1.6954878 0.9888592
#3  c 0.9664587 0.8151934 0.1046694 0.8623137 0.1411871 1.6775071 0.9888592
#4  d 0.6509055 0.2539684 0.6461509 0.8417851 0.7767125 1.0957535 0.9888592
```

Comment: The part that's missing is that I would like to be able to use the column selection functions that `?select` provides such as starts_with, ends_with, etc. Those will not work "nicely" outside of `select()`.

Comment: Of course I could use `cols <- dplyr:::num_range(names(dd), "X", c(2,4))`. The thing is it wouldn't be a part of the chain and it would also break if any column orders are changed in the chain after the column indexes are calculated. It would be better to do it "on demand" if possible

Comment: @MrFlick, I see what you mean. Just got it wrong at first.

Answer (score 2):

A number-of-columns agnostic approach using dplyr:

```
dd %>% 
  select(-id) %>% 
  mutate(evensum = rowSums(.[,1:length(.[1,])%%2==0]), 
         evenmean = rowMeans(.[,1:length(.[1,])%%2==0])) %>% 
  cbind(id=dd[,1],.)

  id        X1        X2        X3        X4        X5   evensum  evenmean
1  a 0.6021140 0.3670719 0.6872308 0.5090904 0.4474437 0.8761623 0.4380812
2  b 0.1950439 0.9888592 0.8314290 0.7066286 0.9646670 1.6954878 0.8477439
3  c 0.9664587 0.8151934 0.1046694 0.8623137 0.1411871 1.6775071 0.8387535
4  d 0.6509055 0.2539684 0.6461509 0.8417851 0.7767125 1.0957535 0.5478767
```

Answer (score 1):

`tidyr::nest()` understands the same selector syntax as `dplyr::select()`, so one approach would be to consolidate the columns of interest into a single column-of-dataframes, perform the necessary operations on that column-of-dataframes, and unnest to get back a flat data frame:

```
library( tidyverse )
dd %>% nest( X2, X4, .key="Slice" ) %>%
    mutate( evensum = map(Slice, rowSums),
           evenmean = map(Slice, rowMeans),
           evensd = map(Slice, pmap_dbl, lift_vd(sd)) ) %>%
    unnest
#   id       X1    X3    X5 evensum evenmean evensd    X2    X4
# 1 a     0.602 0.687 0.447   0.876    0.438 0.100  0.367 0.509
# 2 b     0.195 0.831 0.965   1.70     0.848 0.200  0.989 0.707
# 3 c     0.966 0.105 0.141   1.68     0.839 0.0333 0.815 0.862
# 4 d     0.651 0.646 0.777   1.10     0.548 0.416  0.254 0.842
```

Since data frames are basically lists, this approach is naturally suited for applying arbitrary functions (such as `sd` above) to arbitrary an set of columns using `purrr::pmap()` family of functions.

Side note: Since `sd` works on vectors, we use `purrr::lift_vd` to convert its interface to be suitable for `pmap`:

```
sd( c(0.367, 0.509) )        # 0.100
lift_vd(sd)( 0.367, .509 )   # 0.100
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `rowwise()` plus `c_across()`. This type of operation won't work with `rowSums` or `rowMeans` but will work with the regular `sum()` and `mean()` functions. The `c_across()` function returns multiple columns as a simple vector. It also accepts any of the tidyselect helper functions. So for example you can do

```
dd %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    evensum = sum( c_across(all_of(cols)) ), 
    evenmean = mean( c_across(all_of(cols)) )
)
```

Comment: You can make it work without `rowwise` (which is very slow)
`dd %>% 
  mutate(
    evensum = rowSums(across(all_of(cols))), 
    evenmean = rowMeans(across(all_of(cols)))
)`

Answer (score 0):

Use `across` with `all_of` (or `any_of`)

```r
dd %>% 
  mutate(
    evensum = rowSums(across(all_of(cols))), 
    evenmean = rowMeans(across(all_of(cols)))
)
```