# Using dplyr rowwise with range of columns without enumerating column names

Tags: r, dplyr

Is it possible to refer to 'all columns' or a range of columns in combination with `rowwise()` in `dplyr` without having to enumerate all individual column names?

For example, in the following, I would rather not specify each of the first 7 column names, but rather say `1:7` or something. Can't seem to get it to work. Must be missing something simple.

```
mtcars %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(sillyMetric = mean(c(mpg, cyl, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec))) %>%
  .$sillyMetric
```

Please don't tell me how I don't need `rowwise()` for this case. I obviously have a different problem I am trying to solve that requires it. I want to know if there is a way to not have to enumerate all column names with `rowwise`. **I DON'T want** any other solutions that compute this above `sillyMetric` more efficiently.

Comment: What about `rowMeans(mtcars[,1:7])`?

Comment: :) Read my last comment.

Comment: If you have a different problem you are trying to solve, then you should update your question to include an example that shows what kind of problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: It is a minimal, reproducible example. Not sure why you are insisting I elaborate further as to what I need. I simply need to not have to enumerate the column names with `rowwise`.

Comment: To silence the objectors, just use a slightly more complicated function that doesn't have a row-focused implementation. Replace `mean(c(...))` with `quantile(c(...), probs = 0.314)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751023/performing-dplyr-mutate-on-subset-of-columns. All the answers basically hack `rowMeans` (which would just be `mean` in your case) inside a `mutate` anyway. The simplicity normally gained by using `dplyr` over base seems outweighed by how hacky the solutions will end up.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with rowwise up front. You will probably need to take a step back and re-think how you are addressing the rest of your code. Being able to calculate based on the row ID may yield fruitful. Something like this:

```
mtcars %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(metric, val, 1:7) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(SillyMetric = mean(val))
```

At worst you could just do this separately in then join it in with a left join.

Comment: This is actually a very good general idea. It may even turn out to be much faster. Let me see how it works.

Comment: let us know how it turns out!